# Android In App Billing From PreferenceScreen

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

I have never really had to ask a question here.  Almost any question I can think of has already been asked and answered.  Thus the reason I have never registered.

However, I have finally run across something that I cannot find an answer for.  I assume it would be fairly simple.

I am trying to implement in app billing for an android project I am working on.  I typically code in C# and use Unity to build the .APK.

However, this time I have to make modifications in Eclipse to some PreferenceScreens.

I have an xml file with some string-arrays set up for a ListPreference under my PreferenceScreen.  These ListPreference values are then passed to UnityPlayer for a method.  That's all set up.

I am trying to figure out a way to set up in app billing to trigger on selection of one of my list preference, or preference items.

I can probably figure a lot of it out on my own, but I need help with a function to do something pulling from a string value in the list preferences.  Does this make sense?

I don't expect to be spoon fed, so if I can just get help on a few lines for this I would appreciate it.  Of course I won't complain if anyone wants to write up a little 20 liner function to do it for me.

Thanks in advance,

John

** edit **

Here is the xml from the preferenceScreen I need to address with android In App Billing from Java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="wallpaper_settings"
    android:title="@string/wallpaper_settings" >

    <!-- Ad Placeholder -->
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="rotate"
        android:summary="@string/rotateSummary"
        android:title="@string/rotateTitle" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="doubleTap"
        android:summary="@string/doubleTapSummary"
        android:title="@string/doubleTapTitle" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="swipeEmul"
        android:summary="@string/simulateSwipeSummary"
        android:title="@string/simulateSwipeTitle" />
    <ListPreference 
        android:entryValues="@array/cameraValues" 
        android:defaultValue="MainCamera" 
        android:entries="@array/whichCam" 
        android:summary="@string/cameraSummary" 
        android:dialogTitle="@string/cameraTitles" 
        android:title="@string/cameraTitles" 
        android:key="whichCam"/>

</PreferenceScreen>'
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, the preferred way to write questions is to go straight to the problem. This way is easier for people who answer and also for other ones with the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  My apologies if I did not structure my question correctly.  I will see if I can be a bit more specific to help out anyone with the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very generic, on an Android application you might do this by creating an Activity, then starting that activity from your preference "onClick" method and then, once the activity starts, you load all your in app billing stuff (showing a progress dialog) and finally present the "buy" dialog. Is this what you need?

Comment: Frank, thank you for your response.  The first part is more of what I am looking for.  I am not sure how to interact with the XML of the PreferenceScreens at all in Java.  As enrico has suggested, I will upload some code later today and be a little bit more specific.  Thanks again!

Comment: I added a bit of my code to be more specific about what I need to grab out of xml.